# How do I fix a broken tile?

Tags: tile

I broke a tile and am trying to work out how I can fix it. Any ideas?

[image: Broken Tile]

Comment: The proper way is to replace the tile, which would require removing the broken tile without damaging the rest.  If this is a low traffic area, and you don't mind seeing a slight crack, you might be able to (temporarily) reset the broken piece. Remove the piece, clean the area, apply some mortar to the back of the piece and the hole it came from, then set the piece back in place (pressing down firmly with a slight wiggle). The fix probably won't last forever, but it might last until you can find a matching replacement tile.

Comment: mortar - can I buy a tube of this from Home Depot? If so what would it be called? Or is this something I have to mix?

Comment: I don't think they sell premixed mortar, you'll have to mix your own.  You'll probably have to buy a 25lbs bag of mix, and you'll have to scale the recipe way down so you don't waste a ton of it.  For this fix (since it's only temporary), you might be able to get away with using construction adhesive instead. Just glue the piece back in place. I'd use either [QUIKRETE® Construction Adhesive](http://www.quikrete.com/productlines/polyconstructionadhesive.asp), or [Liquid Nails® Heavy Duty Construction Adhesive](http://www.liquidnails.com/products/product.jsp?productId=35)

Answer (score 4):

The tile broke because it was not supported, that is the hard part for you to fix. Remove the broken piece, and see if there is simply a gap underneath, or if there is no pad/foundation at all to build on. If there is nothing but dirt or air underneath, then you need mortar and and enough of a base that it ties into the existing pad and is also below the frost line. This will be hard to do properly without removing additional tiles. If there is just a gap and there is something directly below to support it, and if the gap is small enough, I would use a two part epoxy to repair. I know some brands in the dual tube packages say they work for masonry on the label, and I have used them in the past for similar repairs. Epoxy is stable, resilient, and thin enough that you wont hardly notice the crack. If you get freezing winters in your area make sure there is no place for water to get in and freeze or it will only break again.